# How to simulate a Polya urn (Martingale) like problem?

Tags: r, for-loop, simulation

> In a village there are living N=100 people and they decide with an
> interesting way about some actions. Specifically, if someone proposes
> an action, then all the N villagers vote for it with YES or NO. The
> next day each villager re-adjusts her/his opinion independently from
> the other villagers, and votes again with probability equal to the
> probability of the total (maximum) supporters of the previous day.This
> voting process continues until all N=100 agree on the same opinion.

**Question:**

How many voting days must pass until all N villagers vote the same ?

**My effort**

The answer must be the number of iterations needed.

I want to simulate in R this process which is a Polya Urn like (I believe) process but here we don't have red =1 and green = 1 ball in the urn.We have N balls (voters).

Also we have random `i` people in YES and `j` people on NO on X_{0} the first day.

Therefore we have p = i/N and q =j/n.

Now the next day each villager will vote again but with probability equal to maximum probability of the previous day.
Something like

```
votevillage <- function(n) {
  i = sample(1:N,1);i
  j = N-i;j
  p = i/N;p
  q = 1-p;q
  support = max(i,j)
  while (support != n) {
    vote = sample(c("YES","NO"),1,prob=c(1-p,p))
    support = support + vote
  }
  if (vote == "YES") 
    return(1) 
  else 
    return(0)
}   

n = 100
trials =  100000
simlist = replicate(trials, votevillage(n))
mean(simlist)
```

The above code is wrong.It's my idea (something like a pseudo code).

Comment: Only 1 day of voting is required.  You might want to reword what your actual question is.

Comment: No.Because the next voting day there will still be supporters of the other side.

Comment: Not if they all vote for the same thing on the first day. Maybe more constraints need to be added but I didn't see anything that prevented that and the question only asked about the number of days that *must* pass. For a thing that everybody agrees on then only one day. Even without a unanimous vote on day one then two days is possible.

Comment: So maybe you just need to rethink the question you're asking or provide more constraints.

Comment: @Dason Interesting…!!!Can you please provide a simulation on your approach proving that that needs 1 or 2 days?

Comment: No simulation needed. Just that you didn't provide any constraints about the initial distribution so if it's possible for everybody to agree (or everybody disagree) then it's the case that you only need one day of voting. If that's not the case then it's still possible no matter how unlikely for everybody to vote the same way on the second day. You didn't say anything about probability thresholds or how likely anything needed to be. That's the point I was making.

Comment: Because keep in mind your question is as stated "How many voting days must pass until all N villagers vote the same". Which completely allows for fringe events no matter how unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it depends of course on the distribution of `yes` voters in the first round (if all villagers voted `yes` (`no`) on the first round the whole election lasts only 1 day.

The following lines show how to simulate the voting:

```r
nr_of_yes_votes <- function(prob, N) {
   rbinom(1, N, prob)
}

nr_of_days_until_unanimity <- function(x0, N) {
   i <- 1
   x <- x0
   while (x < N && x > 0) {
      p <- x / N
      x <- nr_of_yes_votes(p, N)
      i <- i + 1
   }
   i
}

simulate <- function(prob0, N = 100, seed = 123, reps = 10000) {
   set.seed(seed)
   x0 <- nr_of_yes_votes(prob0, N)
   mean(replicate(reps, nr_of_days_until_unanimity(x0, N)))
}

simulate(.5) ## 137.9889
simulate(0)  ## 1
simulate(1)  ## 1
```

Intuitively, the more disagreement in the beginning the longer it will take to get to unanimity. Furthermore, the problem is symmetric. Thus, we would expect something where the numebr of days peaks when there is maximum disagreement in the first voting (which corresponds to an initial voting probability of `0.5`) and which declines symmetrically as we vome closer to `0` (`1`).

This can be nicely shown wiht the following lines:

```r
ns <- vapply((p0 <- seq(0, 1, by = .01)), simulate, numeric(1))
plot(p0, ns, type = "l", xlab = expression(Prob[0]), 
     ylab = "Expected Days")
```

[image: Number of days per initial probability]